# In mozilla my button not look good as it shown in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, browser, mozilla

I want to show my button in Mozilla like Chrome so please help me what will I do for it. 
This is my code.

**CSS:**

```
.green {
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9CD645 0%, #8AC530 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
     border: 1px solid #82B436;
}

.large {
     font-size: 18px;
}
.btn {
     border: 1px solid #82B436;
     border-radius: 25px;
     box-shadow: 0 1px rgba(99, 159, 8, 0.35);
     color: #508400;
     display: inline-block;
     font-weight: bold;
     padding: 3px 12px;
     text-decoration: none;
     text-transform: uppercase;
}

.green {
     background-color: #8CC63F;
 }

.btn span {
     background: url("images/icon_arrows.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
     display: block;
     float: right;
     height: 18px;
     margin: 5px;
     width: 18px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href="smoodees" class="btn large green">
    Check out our Smoodees
    <span></span>
</a>
```

Comment: What's the exact problem you're having?  They look the same to me in both browsers.

Comment: problem is that the icon on button not align in mozilla

Comment: in mozilla icon go to next line and button height is increase

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout this fiddle:

```
http://jsfiddle.net/realdeepak/gvC9z/1/
```

or For browser compatibility in firefox, you can use css hack like this:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
  .large {
    font-size: 17px;
  }
}
```

Or Try this, And fix minor css padding alignment as per your screen:

```
<style type="text/css">
 .green {
     background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #9CD645 0%, #8AC530 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
     border: 1px solid #82B436;
}

.large {
     font-size: 18px;
}
.btn {
border: 1px solid #82B436;
border-radius: 25px;
box-shadow: 0 1px rgba(99, 159, 8, 0.35);
color: #508400;
display: inline-block;
font-weight: bold;
padding: 3px 30px 3px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: uppercase;
position: relative;
}

.green {
     background-color: #8CC63F;
 }

.btn span {
     background: url("images/icon_arrows.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
     height: 18px;
     margin: 5px;
     width: 18px;
     position: absolute;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
}

</style>
```

Comment: i have a problem with icon in span it show ok in chrome but not in mozilla . icon goes to next line in mozilla

Comment: @user3278839, I have updated my answer. If possible use, position property for this scenario.

Comment: @user3278839, Anything else!

Comment: padding is not a problem its position mater of icon

Comment: check my fiddle link. Hope you looking for this. http://jsfiddle.net/realdeepak/gvC9z/1/

Answer (score 0):

Changing the answer completely.

Try this structure:

> <a href="smoodees" class="btn large green">
>       <p id="text">Check out our Smoodees</p>
>       <span></span>
>   </a>

and change the CSS like so:

> #id{
>   float: left
>   }
>
> span{
>   float: left
>   }

edit: For multiple buttons, change the ID to a Class

Comment: i have problem with icon which is call on span as a background-image.. icon not align in firefox

Comment: https://dev.xcluesiv.com/linssmoodees/ check it on firefox this button icon not align as shown in chrome

Comment: size of icon 18px by 18 px

Comment: on main page slider button is create problem the icon is not align plz check

Comment: Try changing display:block to display:inline-block